# How can I make OrderedSet pickleable?

Tags: python-3.x, set, pickle

The python documentation of collections links to a recipie for an `OrderedSet` datatype. This class behaves like a set, but maintains insertion order.

Link (at bottom of page):
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=orderedset

Link target:
https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/

I would now like to make this class pickleable, but the doubly-linked list leads to recursion errors. As a solution, I have added the following methods to this class:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    """ Avoids max depth RecursionError when dumping with pickle"""
    return list(self)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    """ Tells pickle how to restore instance using state """
    self.__init__(state)
```

This works, but it strikes me as hacky to call `__init__` inside `__setstate__`. Also, it requires reconstructing the linked lists from scratch. Is there a better way to make this class pickleable?

Comment: There is technically nothing wrong with calling `__init__` multiple times.

Comment: What is the actual problem? You seem to have a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: Also, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Your question would be more appropriate there.

Comment: I think I am not the only person to encounter this specific question. I will provide my solution as an answer if no one else answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mad Physicist in a comment ([How can I make OrderedSet pickleable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613729/how-can-i-make-orderedset-pickleable#comment88237388_50613729)), the solution proposed in the question is a reasonable one. Defining the following methods for the OrderedSet class gives pickle the information it needs to store and then reconstruct the content of the OrderedSet:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    """ Avoids max depth RecursionError when dumping with pickle"""
    return list(self)

def __setstate__(self, state):
    """ Tells pickle how to restore instance using state """
    self.__init__(state)
```

Internally, pickle will store the content of the `OrderedSet` as a `list`, and then can reconstruct the `OrderedSet` by calling the `__init__()` method of `OrderedSet` with the stored list.

As a bonus, `copy.deepcopy()` falls back to pickle/unpickle, so `copy.deepcopy()` will work now too.